# Combo box on change Listener in Embers js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ember.js, handlebars.js

using below code i show combo box in ember .

```
{{view  "select"  content=model    prompt="Please select a name"  selectionBinding="App.selectedComboBoxController.model"  optionValuePath="content.fullName" optionLabelPath="content.title"   }}
```

> output
>   *http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jodaqumoba/1/edit?html,css,js,output*

my requirement is  combobox changing time how can i call below **submit** function

```
App.ComboBoxRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function () {     
          return posts;     
    },
    actions: {
        submit: function () {
           textId = document.getElementById("emnn");
           textId = textId.value;
            alert(textId);
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an observer to the combobox value. In the observer send an action which will bubble up the route.

[Here is the working demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fikezo/1/edit?html,js)

```
App.SelectedComboBoxController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  model:null,

  selectionChanged: function() {
    this.send('submit', this.get('model'));
  }.observes('model')
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [
      {fullName:"the full name1", title:"the title1"},
      {fullName:"the full name2", title:"the title2"},
      {fullName:"the full name3", title:"the title3"}
    ];
  },
  actions: {
    submit: function (item) {
      alert(item.fullName);
    }
  }
});
```